# Skipping blank lines and doing math on subsequent non-blank lines

Tags: excel

So I am interested in using excel to analyze a data set the data is layed out similar to below

```
Color  | WEIGHT  
------ | ------  
Blue   | 1000  
Blue   | 2000  
Blue   | 3000  
Red    | 4225  
Red    | 5000  
Red    | 5750  
Yellow | 6250  
Red    | 7220
Red    | 9280
Blue   | 9720
Blue   | 11000
Blue   | 12000
```

I would then like to find the amount of weight gained so for example blue initial value 1000 final value 3000 change of 2000. And For red 5750-3000 = change of 2750 I know how to find when a color change occurs eg. If(A1<>A2,A1,0). doing this gives me an output like

```
Color  | WEIGHT  
------ | ------  
Blue   | 1000  | 1000
Blue   | 2000  |
Blue   | 4225  | 
Red    | 4225  | 4225
Red    | 5000  | 
Red    | 5750  |
Yellow | 5750  | 5750
Yellow | 7220  |
Red    | 7220  | 7220
Red    | 9280  |
Blue   | 9280  | 9280
Blue   | 11000 |
Blue   | 12000 | 1200
```

I would like to make a new table that shows the color and the weight change.
 With outputs similar to the following

I am using the following formula to get the output

```
=IFERROR(MMULT(AGGREGATE({14,15},6,$B$1:$B$78/($A$1:$A$78=G2),1),{1;-1}),"")
```

Credit to @XOR LX for the above formula
where my color selection is in G2 and my data is in A and B

Using this formula I can get an output like

```
Color|Change  
Blue  | 11000   
Red   | 5055
Yellow| 970
```

Instead I would like to get an output like the following.

```
Color|Change  
Blue  | 3225   eg (4225-1000)
Red   | 1525
Yellow| 1570
Red   | 2060
Blue  | 2720
```

Comment: Your colors are sorted in an ascending manner. Are they **always** sorted in an ascending manner?

Comment: No they are not. It could go Like red,red,red,blue,blue,white,white,red,red,red @Jeeped

Comment: The weights will always be in ascending order

Comment: If '*It could go Like red,red,red,blue,blue,white,white,red,red,red*' then you need to supplement your sample data with a better example.

Comment: So are you going to be generating the entries in the Color column of your results table, or does this also need to form part of the solution?

Comment: I have a set list of possible colors. I am not sure exactly what you are asking @XORLX

Comment: But some of the colours in your results table are duplicated, i.e. "Blue" and "Red", so it's not necessarily simply the case for you to list each of your colours just once. Hence my question re creating this part of the table.

Comment: Yes,  that is correct my colors can be duplicated in the list unfortunately. So it is true that I cant list each color just once. I can pull a list of the colors so that I get an output like blue,red,yellow,red,blue, but I don't know how to modify the formula you provided to not have it combine the first and last blue. @XORLX

Comment: How do you arrive at your last result, i.e. Blue|2280? As you stated in your comment to my post "the data also spans from the first mention of the color to the first mention of the next color", but in this case there is no "next color". Can you clarify?

Comment: The query is run each day from 6am to 6pm and I receive the color data and weight data. In the situation where there is no color after the color we consider that last data point to be the end of the run so for the last blue the weight would span from 9280 Lbs to 12000 to 9280 lbs. Unfortunately, I seem to be poor at inputing my data the last result should read 2720.  @XORLX

Comment: My solution thus far is to first find the row number of when the color change occurs and then update the aggregate function that you provided me so that the range of data only correlates up to the row of the color change and the row of the next color change. Is there a more elegant solution?@XORLX

Comment: Post updated based on your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Array formula****:

`=MMULT(INDEX(B:B,N(IF(1,SMALL(IF(MMULT(COUNTIF(E2,CHOOSE({1,2},A$1:A$14,A$2:A$15)),{1;1})=1,LOOKUP(ROW(A$2:A$15),ROW(A$2:A$14))),2*COUNTIF(E$2:E2,E2)-{1,0})))),{-1;1})`

where it is assumed that:

1) You have `Excel 2010` or later

2) Your table is in `A1:B14` (with headers in row 1)

3) Your colour of choice, e.g. "Blue", is in `E2`

Copy down to give similar results for colours in `E3`, `E4`, etc.

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: Hey this works great, but I left out a few details when I originally made the question. A few details I left out are that the data may go blue,blue,blue,red,red,red,blue,blue,yellow,green etc. And the data also spans from the first mention of the color to the first mention of the next color. For example. For the first blue data set it would actually span from the value 1000 to the value of 4225 which is the first value of red not the last value of blue

Comment: Seems to work well, besides one small issue it appears to give the output for the next color instead of the color in E2. EDIT: Disregard works great once I added a header at E1

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate you continuing to help me

Comment: Ah, just realised that I mistakenly posted the formula for row 3, not row 2. Hence your issue with the headers. Have amended.