# Excel Aggregate Only Applying Formula to each separated instance of data separately

Tags: excel, aggregate

So I am interested in using excel to analyze a data set the data is layed out similar to below

```
Color  | WEIGHT  
------ | ------  
Blue   | 1000  
Blue   | 2000  
Blue   | 3000  
Red    | 4225  
Red    | 5000  
Red    | 5750  
Yellow | 6250  
Red    | 7220
Red    | 9280
Blue   | 9720
Blue   | 11000
Blue   | 12000
```

I would then like to find the amount of weight gained so for example blue initial value 1000 final value 3000 change of 2000. And For red 5750-3000 = change of 2750 I know how to find when a color change occurs eg. If(A1<>A2,A1,0). doing this gives me an output like

```
Color  | WEIGHT  
------ | ------  
Blue   | 1000  | 1000
Blue   | 2000  |
Blue   | 4225  | 
Red    | 4225  | 4225
Red    | 5000  | 
Red    | 5750  |
Yellow | 5750  | 5750
Yellow | 7220  |
Red    | 7220  | 7220
Red    | 9280  |
Blue   | 9280  | 9280
Blue   | 11000 |
Blue   | 12000 | 1200
```

I would like to make a new table that shows the color and the weight change.
 With outputs similar to the following

I am using the following formula to get the output

```
=IFERROR(MMULT(AGGREGATE({14,15},6,$B$1:$B$78/($A$1:$A$78=G2),1),{1;-1}),"")
```

Credit to @XOR LX for the above formula
where my color selection is in G2 and my data is in A and B

where my color selection is in G2 and my data is in A and B

Using this formula I can get an output like

```
Color|Change  
Blue  | 11000   
Red   | 5055
Yellow| 970
```

Instead I would like to get an output like the following.

```
Color|Change  
Blue  | 3225   eg (4225-1000)
Red   | 1525
Yellow| 1570
Red   | 2060
Blue  | 2280
```

Comment: Do not ignore [your previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44548564/skipping-blank-lines-and-doing-math-on-subsequent-non-blank-lines). If they were not helpful then fine but if you have changed the conditions of the question, acknowledge the valid contribution(s) before reposting what is essentially the same question.

Comment: I mean seriously, not only have you completely ignored the effort(s) put together for your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44548564/skipping-blank-lines-and-doing-math-on-subsequent-non-blank-lines) largely because you '*left out a few details when I originally made the question*', you have also shamelessly taken that effort and posted it here posing as your own effort with no accreditation to the actual author. Bad form matey.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because any original effort shown was plagiarized from a [response to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44548564/skipping-blank-lines-and-doing-math-on-subsequent-non-blank-lines/44549155#44549155) which has been ignored due to the fact that the OP '*left out a few details when I originally made the question*'.